# HTML - HREF technical standard for back-referencing directories

Tags: html, standards, href

This may be completely irrelevant, but maybe you've noticed that:

```
<a href="./some-file.html">Some File</a>
```

And:

```
<a href="some-file.html">Some File</a>
```

both instruct the browser agent to go to the same URL. The question is, which, if any, is better, and why? Maybe it is merely preference, but I found it worth clarifying...

NOTE: and by "better", I mean, less error-prone with regard to cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: Using the `.` specifically calls out where to go; the current directory.  Otherwise, the second case also calls out the current directory.  They are semantically the same.  The major browsers will all treat them identically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From ["Uniform Resource Identifiers (URI): Generic Syntax"](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) (Section 4, URI References)

> "Within a relative-path reference, the complete path segments "." and
>   ".." have special meanings: "the current hierarchy level" and "the
>   level above this hierarchy level", respectively.  Although this is
>   very similar to their use within Unix-based filesystems to indicate
>   directory levels, these path components are only considered special
>   when resolving a relative-path reference to its absolute form"

From the same document (Section 5.2 Resolving Relative References to Absolute Form, 6, c):

> "The relative path needs to be merged with the base URI's path." ... "All occurrences of "./", where "." is a complete path segment, are removed from the buffer string."

So, to the URI parser, "./" and "" are equal.

EDIT: The RFC quoted above has been obsoleted by http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt . The relevant section of that (as far as I can determine) is Section 5.2.4.  Remove Dot Segments .

Comment: I thought it would be a commonly asked question, with a fairly definitive answer. Where are the "community wiki guidelines"? searching through meta, I see lots of conflicting info, and there isn't anything obvious in the FAQ.

Comment: The RFC cited was obsoleted in 2005 by RFC 3986, also known as [STD 66](http://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc3986). The formulation there is different, but the basic point remains: at the start of a URI, `./` is ignored (by the browser or other client resolving a relative URI, so this is pure string manipulation and has nothing to do with files and directories).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela thanks for the update, will update my answer with a link to relevant section of the RFC.